# SDL_ACTIVEEVENT equivalent in SDL 2.0?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

Is there an SDL_ACTIVEEVENT equivalent in SDL 2.0? How do we handle SDL_APPMOUSEFOCUS and SDL_APPINPUTFOCUS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SDL2's [`SDL_WindowEvent`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_WindowEvent):

- `SDL_APPMOUSEFOCUS` maps to `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_ENTER` and `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_LEAVE`
- `SDL_APPINPUTFOCUS` maps to `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_FOCUS_GAINED` and `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_FOCUS_LOST`.

Comment: Which one is the equivalent to `SDL_ACTIVEEVENT`? E.g. `SDL_MouseButtonEvent`only has `SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` or `SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP`